# BeautifulSoup take the url of imported moduls

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

Is it possible to take from a html code value of url from lines:

```
@import url("/modules/system/system.menus.css?n98t0f");
@import url("/modules/system/system.messages.css?n98t0f");
```

I was trying to use `soup.findAll('import')` or `soup.findAll('@import')` but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`soup.find_all()` can only find elements **containing** such import statements; you'll then have to extract the text from there:

```
import re

for style_tag in soup.find_all('style', text=re.compile('@import\s+url')):
    style_text = style_tag.get_text()
    urls = re.findall(r'@import url\("([^"]+)"\)', style_text)
    print urls
```

Comment: So it means that I can change the value of url's in import in a quick way? I wanted to find this urls to modify it a little bit, for example attach a string to the front of this urls for example www.something.com

Comment: @Ziva: you'd have to use string manipulation to change that text, or find a CSS parsing library.

Answer (score 2):

Through python's re module,

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """@import url("/modules/system/system.menus.css?n98t0f");
... @import url("/modules/system/system.messages.css?n98t0f");"""
>>> m = re.findall(r'(?<=@import url\(\")[^"]*', s)
>>> for i in m:
...     print i
... 
/modules/system/system.menus.css?n98t0f
/modules/system/system.messages.css?n98t0f
```